# Contains Text into item list Sharepoint Microsoft Graph

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I have a question. I need to search a sharepoint list and retrieve an item via Microsoft Graph.
Is there any way to do the equivalent of a **contains** instead of an **equals**?

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{site_id}}/lists/{{list_id}}/items?expand=fields&filter=fields/Field1 eq 'Something'`

Return items if there is a full match in the Field1 field.

I can't use queries because I use application permission.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will recommend Rest api to Realize the contain function

```
 /_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Address')/items?$select=Title,Id,Company,City&$filter=substringof('e',Company)
```

graph api has startswith and endswith can Realize part of the function

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{site_id}}/lists/{{list_id}}/items?$expand=fields&$filter=startswith(fields/Title,'e')
```